# python Datetime - extract year and month

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

How to extract month and year from a `string` in `DateTime` stamp format?

```
sales_close_7 = 2018-12-07
```

Comment: I need it in datetime format not in string

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

sales_close_7 = '2018-12-07'
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(sales_close_7, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

print(date_object.year)
Output: 2018
print(date_object.month)
Output: 12
```

Comment: Bro I need it in this format '2018-12' in datetime format, Can you please help me out?

Comment: @affadamseven new_date = str(date_object.year)+'-'+str(date_object.month)